# why :"*p doesn't work at all?

Tags: vim

I am using git bash.

type

```
:reg
```

It will get:

```
"-   the
"*   Neovim
".   edir
":   ["*]p
"%   README.md
"/   \<the\>
```

and

```
:"*p
```

will get nothing, the content stored in `"*` won't be pasted to the buffer.

Why?

Answer (score 8):

`:p` is `:print`, which is not the paste command, and the syntax is all wrong anyway. `"*p` as a *normal mode* command (notice the absence of colon) pastes the `*` register. The corresponding *ex* command (with colon) is `:put` (not `:paste`, as one might think), that can be abbreviated to `:pu` (not `:p`), and the register comes after it as a parameter, not before it (which is where the range would go): `:pu *`

By default this will put it under the current line; if you specify the range, it puts it there; so to put it as the top line, you would say `:0pu *`, to put it as the last line `:$pu *`

Comment: I can’t find it in the article, can you edit your question and quote the paragraph if you want me to take a closer look?

Comment: No, that (bad) article didn't tell you to use the wrong syntax.